# Can I use NHibernate as a standardized way to communicate with different database engines?

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate

I just asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108085/is-there-any-general-sql-way-to-get-tables-names-and-create-tables) if there was a general way to get tables names and created tables on a database.

I need this because my application connects to a database and has some basic database edition functionality like creating tables with a wizard. But now I want the user to be able to select from a range of possible database engines (right now it only uses the Jet engine).

Most people told me this was not possible and that I would need to create an abstract layer with implementations for each database engine. But I just found NHibernate and it seems to me that it generates SQL queries for a wide range of database engine (I'm not sure if the Jet engine is included). So my question is, can I use NHibernate to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can, as long as the database schema is the same across the different databases**.

Here's a list of database engines supported by NHibernate ([including Microsoft Jet](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate#Microsoft_Access)) and the configuration settings required in order to work with them:

- [Databases supported by NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate)

However be aware that **the level of support for the different database engines may vary**, so make sure you research any known issues NHibernate may have with the specific database you are going to use.

Comment: Can you change the database schema at runtime? (see my comment on the other question)

Comment: If you generate the database schema from the classes in your domain model, you could use modify the NHibernate mappings at runtime and use the `NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` class to generate and run a DDL script that will modify the underlying database schema.

Comment: However I should point out the ORMs are generally not geared towards supporting scenarios where the database schema and/or the application domain model change dynamically at runtime. If this is what you need then you should probably look for a different solution where you have more control over the Data Layer. For example you could implement your Data Layer using ADO.NET directly and dynamically build SQL statements to match the changing database schema.

Comment: In any case, you can read more about updating the database schema with NHibernate here: http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/28/create-and-update-database-schema.aspx

Answer (score 1):

NHiberate will help you out with the multi db part of your problem. The real challenge is the editing of tables.

I have done something similar to what you want with NHibernate, but the functionality is tricky to implement and difficult to get right.

Because NHibernate is an ORM you first need a class to load the data into so you will need to emit a class first. Then you need to generate a mapping file to map the db columns to the emitted classes properties. You can then uses the generated mapping file and all the other mapping files that your application needs to create the `Configuration`. Finally you can use the schema export functionality of NH to generate the new table.

As I said tricky and not easy, bit possible.

Comment: Do you have to use classes to define your data structures or tables? I want my application to create tables (and its structure) at runtime as you would do with MS Access or any other database editor. Is this possible?

Comment: As I said NH is an ORM so yes you need to create a class. You can create the class at runtime using reflection emit.